# Apple Push Notification Action Buttons

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have set remote notifications for my app and it works as follows.
If the user taps the notification's body, it calls a function (which takes the user to a specific ViewController).
However when the user taps one of the action buttons, the button's action is performed AS WELL AS the body tap action. How can I have the action button perform its action only, without the body performing its action as well.

Here's my code sample:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    completionHandler([.alert,.sound,.badge])
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as! [String:AnyHashable]

    // parse userInfo and execute a function in SWReveal to show the appropriate ViewController

    let action = response.actionIdentifier

    if action == "acceptFriendRequest" {
        print("Friend Request Accepted")
    }
}

func setCategories() {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let acceptFriendRequest = UNNotificationAction(
            identifier: "acceptFriendRequest",
            title: "Accept",
            options: [])
        let rejectFriendRequest = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "rejectFriendRequest", title: "Reject", options: [.destructive])
        let FrReq = UNNotificationCategory(
            identifier: "FrReq",
            actions: [acceptFriendRequest, rejectFriendRequest],
            intentIdentifiers: [],
            options: [.customDismissAction])}
```

Comment: What is your "body" action? I can't see it in the code above. I only see accept and reject.

Comment: The code that triggers the body action is in the `didReceive response`. The parsing code executes a function in SWReveal which pretty much works when the body is tapped. I want to disable that behavior, if the user taps the action buttons.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a way of completely avoiding the method being called as it's a delegate method. However, a simple guard statement in the beginning of the function should do the same trick:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    guard response.actionIdentifier != "acceptFriendRequest" && response.actionIdentifier != "rejectFriendRequest" else { return }

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as! [String:AnyHashable]

    // parse userInfo and execute a function in SWReveal to show the appropriate ViewController

}
```

This way if the action identifier matches either of the actions i.e. the action buttons have been pressed, then the rest of the function won't be executed.